# Lambda expression for an observer used for live data in viewmodel

Tags: java, lambda, android-livedata

It might be a very basic question but please bear with me as am learning the MVVM model and converting my previous codes to this model.

I have searched through stackoverflow because everytime I try to make a lambda, I get an error or data is not observed. I know how to make lambda for Views and others but I got confused on how to make Lambda for observer.

On the first line of code, Android is giving me suggestion to edit new ObserverModel>> into lambda expression.

```
selfTestViewModel.getSelfTestList().observe(this, new Observer<List<Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Model> models) {
            adapter = new Adapter(models, getContext());
            viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: If Android Studio is suggesting to make a change, it will actually make that change for you if you use the keyboard shortcut in the tooltip popup.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is just a grayed out and you see the suggestion when you put your mouse on the grey area

Comment: You might be using a very old version of Android Studio.  Mine gives me keyboard shortcuts for more actions when hovering over gray text.  And when I click in that text, I am also prompted with an light bulb icon to take actions.

Comment: Thank you, I have upgraded to latest android and I get the suggestions you mentioned. You fixed my problem in comments